# Android Java Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

I have Downloaded from github a java Project for Android (food App) and when open it in android Studio it opens on Project not android, so when change it from the menu many other folders appears and understand nothing, What should do to open a project just downloaded from git hub to work on and edit it? I'm a very beginner.

Comment: Not very clear on the ask TBH. One approach you can try is to create your own project and all the wizards to create activities and other components. Copy the contents of the github project into those files and that should work.

Comment: Great Idea, Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a proper Android project you should be able to switch to Android view. Tap the title that says 'Project' above all the folders and files you mentioned. It should show a dropdown with 'Android' as the last item. Select that item and you should see what you're looking for. If no Android option is available from dropdown, it is not a proper Android project.

Comment: That's what happened already, Changed to android but the files don't appear, just a java folder nothing more, any ideas?